# How to get product category data from observer

Tags: category, event-observer

I am using the following to get the complete product data from the observer:

```
$product = $observer->getProduct()->getData();
```

But I could not notice any information about the category of the product.

How can I get the data about the product category, such as category id from the observer?

Comment: What event do you using?

Comment: I am using the event **catalog_controller_product_view**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in your observer:

```
public function yourMethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $categoryId = '';
    if ($category = Mage::registry('current_category')) {
        $categoryId = $category->getId();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

> Okay first of all why the if statement is needed? Second I tried the code updated and previous and still nothing. When I keep the if statement it returns null and without the if statement it gives the error: Call to a member function getId() on null.

The if-statement is required to check if you view a product within a category. Products can also be viewed without category path ... if `$categoryId` returns `null` you are not in a category. Please check URL for the viewed product.

Comment: I tried adding **$category = Mage::registry('current_category')** and **$categoryId = $category->getId()** but this gave me an error: Call to a member function getId() on null .

Comment: Have you used the code as posted? Including `if ($category ...`? Updated answer ...

Comment: Okay first of all why the if statement is needed? Second I tried the code updated and previous and still nothing. When I keep the if statement it returns null and without the if statement it gives the error: Call to a member function getId() on null.

Comment: **$category = Mage::registry('current_category');** with var_dump gives null as well.

Comment: Then you are not in a category ... updated answer for better readablity

Comment: Yeah this makes sense. But I did specify a category for the product when I first added it to the system through admin panel. For example I have a category called Phone Accessories. When I go to **Catalog->Manage Categories** and then **Category Products** I can see the product listed there. So why it's not reckognized? Is there something extra that's needs to be allowed or enabled?

Comment: Even when you assign a product to a category, you can access it in to way 1.) domain.com/product-name.html AND 2.) domain.com/category/product-name.html. Try to go to a category and then view a product ... the `categoryId` should not be `null`.

Comment: Well thanks for help. I got it working, I had kind of a big mess with my categories, I had to recheck everything, which one was root directory and everything under it. Now I'm getting the id of the category.

Comment: @sv3n I am getting error with using category id, could you pls hemp me -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/284557/57334

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$product = $observer->getProduct();
$catIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
//var_dump($catIds);
```

Comment: This works as it gives me the id of the category. But is there any way to get the id from **$product = $observer->getProduct()->getData()**? I need this getData() to get the complete product data. Or should I retrieve the category individually from the rest of the product data?

Comment: Magento do not give category Ids with getData method as category ids assigned different array to product object.

Comment: @PrasantaHatui could you pls help me with my post -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/284557/57334